# Signing pdf documents with self signed certificate in my .NET backend web application that is running on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, digital-signature

I am trying to digitally sign pdf documents with my self signed certificate that is stored on my pc where my IIS server is situated. But for some reason it always gives me the same error when trying to access the certificate within my ASP .NET C# code. The error goes as follows:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18014398523172197183", Request ID "40001340-0003-fa00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
         at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
         at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
         at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__67_0(CspParameters csp)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.Security.X509Certificate2Signature.Sign(Byte[] message)
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.Security.PdfSignatureDictionary.GetPortableStoreCertificate()
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.Security.PdfSignatureDictionary.DocumentSaved(Object sender, DocumentSavedEventArgs e)
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfDocumentBase.OnDocumentSaved(DocumentSavedEventArgs args)
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument.AppendDocument(PdfWriter writer)
         at Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument.Save(Stream stream)
```

Just to be clear yes I know signing the documents with self signed certificates won't verify the signature or the user that signed it outside the signing domain but this is of no importance to me right now.

I tried running the application in development and on localhost and tested it with my own pc's certificate store and this did seem to work maybe it has something to do with IIS not allowing this or?

Also switching from store so for example the StoreLocation.LocalMachine to StoreLocation.CurrentUser didn't do the trick.

Just for reference here is also my C# backend code:

```
// Initialize the Windows store.
X509Store store = new X509Store("My",StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

var rgx = new Regex("[^a-fA-F0-9]");

string tempThumbprint =  rgx.Replace(template.pdfSigningThumbprint, string.Empty).ToUpper();

//Find the certificate using thumb print.

X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, tempThumbprint,false);

if(fcollection.Count < 0)
{
    throw new Exception($"Unable to load certificate by thumbprint {template.pdfSigningThumbprint}");
}

X509Certificate2 digitalID = fcollection[0];

//Load X509Certificate2.
PdfCertificate certificate = new PdfCertificate(digitalID);

//Create a Revision 2 signature with loaded digital ID.
PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(loadedDocument, loadedDocument.Pages[0], certificate, "DigitalSignature");
```

Comment: Hello, can you share the error details, as well as the relevant code in text? Images are not convenient for those reading your question.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I am not used of asking questions here on stackoverflow. my question should be updated now and be more clear.

Comment: Thank you @KJ this actually did it ! you saved me so much work. Is there a way I can like mark your comment as the answer or?